# css is not working in magento2

Tags: magento2, css

This is my  default_head_blocks.xml file code

```
<css src="css/source/_style-l.css" />   
    <css src="css/source/styles-m.css" />
    <css src="css/source/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
    <css src="css/source/print.css" media="print" />
</head>
```

Is an application set to developer mode and all the CSS file incorrect location?

Comment: Are you inheriting from Blank or Luma?

Answer (score 0):

Use This: (**Change the css path as required**)

**<action method="addCss" ifconfig="porto_settings/general/rtl" condition="0"><stylesheet>css/local.css</stylesheet></action>**

Comment: kindly check your answer may be u have given answer for M1 not M2 check it once

Answer (score 0):

First you have to configure compilation of style in admin path given below

```
Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Front-end development workflow
```

change to

```
Client side less compilation
```

Then edit your theme styles module wise and other web/css/source (common style)

```
app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer below link.

```
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html
```

also you need to run command for deploy, you can use anyone command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
or
php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy
```